# how to get a part of a text from a column in the database using tdbnput and print in talend

Tags: javascript, java, talend

[image]

I have a talend job that goes like the above one and i am using a select statement to access the data from oracle

select id,name,details from employee ;

and send the results via email.However for a particular column details it has 10 different lines and that are dynamic and has various other unwanted/irrelevant information and i would like to precisely filter few lines and print them to the mail using tjava component.

How can i do that?

for eg:details column has values like:
"hi i am john
i work at abc
i go to oxford
i reside at 1st street
goodbye"
so the lines are totally random,i would want to match based on a specific keyword lets say "reside at" alone and filter that for different records and capture that in that output?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this you need to create a custom SQL query in the tDBinput.

```
"select id,name,details from employee
where details like '%reside at%'"
```

(Where the % are any text check the SQL "LIKE" function for more details)

With this you will filter the row you want.
If you need more filter you can modify you SQL query like you want.

Comment: thanks for your response,my query goes like this:
"select  id,name,details  FROM employee where  details like '%reside%at%' and newdate>=sysdate-5 and newdate<sysdate order by date_new desc"
But i am trying to retrieve only part of the text as part of the output that is sent to tsendmail and i dont want to print the entire contents from the DETAILS column,makes sense?
And the output should have only DETAILS :reside at 1st street printed via mail component....so extracting only part of it and displaying it rather than entire sentences as such.To keep it precise and short ,thanks